# No error but not showing data on Mat table

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I want to show data from php mysql to my angular mat table. I am using angular CLI 8.1.0. Below is my code, can anyone help what's the actual error.
I made rest api through PHP and MYSQL, and when i hit on postman it gives the database record in json format. But i am not able to show it onto my mat table.

> api.service.ts

```
    import { Injectable, Output,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
    import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Users } from './users';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { Displayvendor } from './adminpanel/home/vendor-action/displayvendor';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class ApiService {          
      private static URL = 'http://localhost/repos/Sportaz-repo/VaamozWeb/VaamozBusiness/RestApi/VaamozStore/AdminStore/angular_admin/php/index.php';

      constructor(private httpClient : HttpClient) { }          
      userList(): Observable<Displayvendor[]> 
      {
        return this.httpClient.get(ApiService.URL).pipe(map((response: {data: Displayvendor[]}) => response.data));
      }         
    }
```

> vendor-action.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {MatSort, MatTableDataSource, MatPaginator} from '@angular/material';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ApiService } from 'src/app/api.service';
import { Displayvendor } from './displayvendor';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-vendor-action',
  templateUrl: './vendor-action.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./vendor-action.component.css']
})
export class VendorActionComponent {

  displayvendors : Displayvendor[];
  constructor(private router:Router,public apiService:ApiService){}

  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.apiService.userList().subscribe(this.assignUsers.bind(this));
  }

  assignUsers(displayvendors:Displayvendor[])
  {
    this.displayvendors=displayvendors;
  }        
}
```

> vendor-action.component.ts

```
<div class="purchases-style">
    <div>
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="displayvendors" class="mat-elevation-z1">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Vendor ID </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="changeColumn">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Change Column </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.changeColumn}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="type">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Change Type </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.type}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="timestamp">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Timestamp </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.timestamp}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Status </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.status}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="['id','changeColumn','type','timestamp','status']"></tr>
        <tr class="rowhover" (click)="displayData(row)" mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['id','changeColumn','type','timestamp','status']"></tr>
        </table>

         <mat-paginator [length]="100" [pageSize]="10" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]" class="mat-elevation-z1">
         </mat-paginator>
     </div>
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

> displayvendor.ts

```
export interface Displayvendor {
    id: number;
    changeColumn: string;
    type: string;
    timestamp: string;
    status: string;
  }
```

Comment: try with: 
 `this.apiService.userList().subscribe(displayvendors=> {
this.displayvendors=displayvendors;
});`

Comment: and remove `async` pipe from your html

Comment: @BartoszTermena didn't worked. No result

Comment: Did you removed `| async` from html : 
`<table mat-table [dataSource]="displayvendors | async" ...` ?

Comment: @BartoszTermena yes i removed

Comment: please, try to console.log your result, like below:
`this.apiService.userList().subscribe(displayvendors=> { 
console.log(displayvendors);
this.displayvendors=displayvendors; });`

Comment: and show what you got

Comment: How can i upload image here?

Comment: copy paste text, or upload somwhere else and paste link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209149/discussion-between-manisha-and-bartosztermena).

Comment: Nothing showing on console also. "Undefined" is showing only

Comment: Remove pipe in your service:
 `userList(): Observable<Displayvendor[]> 
      {
        return this.httpClient.get(ApiService.URL);
      }`

Comment: Type 'Observable<Object>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Displayvendor[]>'.
The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'Displayvendor[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more
error is showing

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an array from Observable Object with Async Pipe change your code to :

```
    export class VendorActionComponent {

      displayvendors : any;
      constructor(private router:Router,public apiService:ApiService){}

      ngOnInit()
      {
        this.displayvendors = this.apiService.userList();
      }
   ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your component

`import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';`

variable should be of type **MatTableDataSource**

`displayvendors: MatTableDataSource<any>`

and assign the array you got from API call to your `displayvendors` like this.

`this.apiService.userList().subscribe(displayvendors=> { 
this.displayvendors = new MatTableDataSource(displayvendors);
})`

This worked for me. idea is to convert your array into mat-table structure which is followed by Angular material